# sed replace special characters followed by newline

Tags: sed

I have the following file

```
"user_id1": "184767",
        "timeStamp": "2017-03-08 19:55:25.000"
    },
    {
        "user_id1": "146364",
        "timeStamp": "2017-03-12 23:48:48.000"
    },
]
```

I want to replace all instances of `},]` with `}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed '/},/N;s/,\n *\]/]/' file
```

When `},` is found, adds next line to the pattern space and replace the new line followed by `]` with `]`.

Comment: I get    "user_id1": "184767",
            "timeStamp": "2017-03-08 19:55:25.000"
        },
        {
            "user_id1": "146364",
            "timeStamp": "2017-03-12 23:48:48.000"
        },]
}
]